# Different LatLng imports

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, importerror, directions

I have some type conflict while using LatLng's.
While this issue does not prevent the app from running without any problems, I want to optimize imports.

I import LatLng like this:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

I can successfully use the imported LatLng like tis:

```
private LatLng[] places = {new LatLng(xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx)
};
```

However after using the Directions API and using the resulting route:

```
List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> decodedPath = PolylineEncoding.decode(route.overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath());
```

The decode function belongs to PolylineEncoding.java, when I check the source code and search for LatLng import I came across with the import:

```
import com.google.maps.model.LatLng;
```

Which differs from my original import

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

My goal here is to use LatLng like this:

```
List<LatLng> decodedPath = PolylineEncoding.decode(route.overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath());
```

When I do that, I get the error(naturally):
[Type conflict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEJXq.png)

How can I resolve this conflict?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can just write a new static method to convert the result of `PolylineEncoding.decode` to the required type. Or use the same type across your code.

Comment: I am not considering to use same type across the code because it will not be good for code clarity. 
About your other suggestion, can you clarify a little bit more of what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, you can just write a static method to convert type:

```
static List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> convertCoordType(List<com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng> list) {
  List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng item : list) {
    resultList.add(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude));
  }
  return resultList;
}
```

Then call `convertCoordType` to wrap around `decode`:

```
List<LatLng> decodedPath = convertCoordType(PolylineEncoding.decode(route.overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath()));
```